# My ORACLE SQL Query is giving error for JSON_OBJECT() and json_array() functions

Tags: sql, json, oracle, object

I am using Oracle 12.2

Following is my Simple SQL

```
SELECT json_object(KEY 'EmployeeDetails' VALUE   
    json_array(
        json_object(KEY 'DepartmentInfo' VALUE 
            json_object(  
                KEY 'EmpNo' VALUE empno, 
                KEY 'Name' VALUE ename  
  )))) json FROM thris_emp_profile@p4hri2p1hri d;
```

is giving folowing error:

```
Error(s), warning(s):

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I just want to get a json output from the SQL

Comment: just to correct its ORACLE 12.2.0.1.0 ..

Comment: And what is the Oracle version of the linked server? `select * from v$version@p4hri2p1hri`

Comment: linked server version  is ORACLE 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: There is your answer.

Comment: Great.. I got to root ..  I just created a materialized view in this server from linked server and now.. its working..